# Creating package/merger of HTML/Javascript/Image files

Tags: html, website, javascript, merge, packages

I have been using a tool called [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) to document code. This has created a folder of `.html` files, `.js` javascript files and `.png` image files, and creates a really nice browser-based documentation by running `index.html` in the folder. 
[image]
However, its not very user friendly - as the user has to find `index.html` in a file with hundreds of others. I have attempted to merge all of these into a single `.html` with a variety of online tools such as HTMLDOC, none of which have worked.

I was wondering a) if there was a way of merging this collection of `html`, `.js` and `.png` files into a single file or b) if not, is there a way of creating a sort of "package" that hides the underlying files, and runs the index page when clicked? Ultimately I want to make it so that the use can click a single file/package called "documentation" rather than look through an enormous list!

Thanks very much,

David

Comment: How about just adding single index.html (or .url shortcut) file in folder above this one, which would just redirect user to specified file in subfolder?

Comment: In the question, I said HTMLDOC didn't work. A URL redirect would be tolerable but I would like it as a single file system item so it doesn't have a folder that has to be moved around with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there are a handful of competing “web archive” formats, and I don’t know of any that are supported by all browsers.